# How to download image and set Image.Source using HttpClient in windows phone?

Tags: c#, image, silverlight, windows-phone-7, dotnet-httpclient

VS2012
project based on Windows Phone OS 7.1
HttpClient via NuGet
Async via NuGet


I want to download a jpg from a source and display it in a Image control.
I google it, found that in windows 8 I can use a InMemoryRandomAccessStream to do it (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/5a550aa2-f873-45cc-b07e-05c4bf5c7ad8/download-image-and-set-imagesource) , 
but how to do it in a windows phone project? There is no InMemoryRandomAccessStream.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to display your picture, you dont have to use the memory.

You can use a `BitmapImage` and a `Uri` :

```
string urlOfImage= "http://i.nokia.com/r/image/view/-/1901852/lowRes/4/-/Nokia-Lumia-900-photoalbum.jpg";
yourImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(urlOfImage, UriKind.Absolute));
```

Comment: the reason I want to download the image via HttpClient is, I need to add a Refer in the Header of http request which can't fulfill by the direct binding uri to image source.

Comment: So download the link with HttpClient and you can put the image into the IsolatedStorage.